# Error: no matching function for call to 'ProcMem::iSizeOfArray(char*&)'

Tags: c++, преобразование-типов

При компиляции проекта получаю следующую ошибку в `ProcMem.h`:

> 64   34 ...\ProcMem.h [Error] no matching function for call to 'ProcMem::iSizeOfArray(char*&)'

В строке `int iSize = iSizeOfArray(Offset) - 1;`  со следующими заметками:

> [Note] candidate is:
>   In file included from ProcMem.cpp
>
> [Note] int ProcMem::iSizeOfArray(int*)
>
> [Note] no known conversion for argument 1 from 'char*' to 'int*'

```
#pragma region TEMPLATE MEMORY FUNCTIONS

//REMOVE READ/WRITE PROTECTION
template <class cData>
void Protection(DWORD dwAddress)
{
    if (!bProt)
        VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)dwAddress, sizeof(cData), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwProtection); //Remove Read/Write Protection By Giving It New Permissions
    else
        VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)dwAddress, sizeof(cData), dwProtection, &dwProtection); //Restore The Old Permissions After You Have Red The dwAddress

    bProt = !bProt;
}

//READ MEMORY 
template <class cData>
cData Read(DWORD dwAddress)
{
    cData cRead; //Generic Variable To Store Data
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)dwAddress, &cRead, sizeof(cData), NULL); //Win API - Reads Data At Specified Location 
    return cRead; //Returns Value At Specified dwAddress
}

//READ MEMORY - Pointer
template <class cData>
cData Read(DWORD dwAddress, char *Offset, BOOL Type)
{
    //Variables
    int iSize = iSizeOfArray(Offset) - 1; //Size Of *Array Of Offsets 
    dwAddress = Read<DWORD>(dwAddress); //HEX VAL

    //Loop Through Each Offset & Store Hex Value (Address)
    for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
        dwAddress = Read<DWORD>(dwAddress + Offset[i]);

    if (!Type)
        return dwAddress + Offset[iSize]; //FALSE - Return Address
    else
        return Read<cData>(dwAddress + Offset[iSize]); //TRUE - Return Value
}

// WRITE MEMORY
template <class cData>
void Write(DWORD dwAddress, cData Value)
{
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)dwAddress, &Value, sizeof(cData), NULL);
}

// WRITE MEMORY - Pointer
template <class cData>
void Write(DWORD dwAddress, char *Offset, cData Value)
{
    Write<cData>(Read<cData>(dwAddress, Offset, false), Value);
}

// Base read
template <typename TYPE>
TYPE RPM(LPVOID lpBaseAddress, SIZE_T nSize)
{
    TYPE data = TYPE();
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, &data, nSize, NULL);
    return data;
}

// Base write
void WPM(LPVOID lpBaseAddress, LPCVOID lpBuffer, SIZE_T nSize)
{
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, lpBuffer, nSize, NULL);
}

// MEMORY FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
virtual bool Process(char* ProcessName); // Return Handle To The Process
virtual void Patch(DWORD dwAddress, char *chPatch_Bts, char *chDefault_Bts); // Write Bytes To Specified Address
virtual void Inject(DWORD dwAddress, char *chInj_Bts, char *chDef_Bts, BOOL Type); // Jump To A Codecave And Write Memory
virtual DWORD AOB_Scan(DWORD dwAddress, DWORD dwEnd, char *chPattern); // Find A Byte Pattern
virtual bool Module(LPSTR ModuleName, DWORD &output); // Return Module Base Address
```

Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сообщение об ошибке достаточно ясное.

У вас объявлена функция `iSizeOfArray` в классе или пространстве имен `ProcMem` как

```
int iSizeOfArray(int*);
                 ^^^^^
```

То есть ее параметр имеет тип `int *`. Однако вы пытаетесь ее вызвать в предложении

```
int iSize = iSizeOfArray(Offset) - 1;
                         ^^^^^^
```

передав в качестве аргумента объект типа `char *`, Смотрите объявление функции `Read`.

```
cData Read(DWORD dwAddress, char *Offset, BOOL Type)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Не сществует неявного преобразования из типа `char *` в тип `int *`.

Вы уж разберитесь с объявлениями ваших функций.:)

Comment: char *Offset поменять на int* Offset?

Comment: @Order_By Вам виднее, так как я не знаю, что эти функции делают, и как они определены.:)

Comment: @Order_By Если у вас возникают трудности с определением данных функций, то вы можете задать новый вопрос, например, как определить функцию iSizeOfArray, которая должна делать то-то и то-то.:) Так как с этим вопросом, то есть с ошибкой компилятора,  мы разобрались.

Comment: Замена char *Offset на int* Offset привела к новой ошибке:  
[Error] 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope в return nullptr;  
Меняю nullptr на NULL, и ошибки в ProcMem.h пропадают. Из огня да в полымя, появляется новая ошибка но уже в другом header'е - functions.h  
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status в строке enum Bones : int

Comment: Ошибка НЕ в строчке enum Bones : int, она вообще не в строчке. Ошибка ...\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status  . Что за зверь collect2 не понятно, его там нет и быть не должно

Comment: @Order_By, это уже ошибка линковки

Comment: @Order_By Вы занимаетесь гаданием. Вам надо сначала разобраться, зачем эта функция существует, что она делает, и нужна ли она вообще в таком виде. Поэтому я и посоветовал вам задать новый вопрос.